# Unable to trigger pull request release in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have set up a pull request release trigger in the following way.

I want to deploy Artifacts from `VerifyApiTestEnvironment` branch whenever pull request into that branch is successfully completed.

[image]

This is how my artifacts look.

[image]

This is how my CD trigger looks like.

[image]

This is how my pre-deployment conditions look like.

[image]

This is how my policy screen looks.

[image]

This is how my branch structure looks. I am always getting an error in the build saying source branch missing the changes from master when I complete the pull request targeting the `VerifyApiTestEnvironment` branch. What could be the reason behind this?

Every time I am committing my changes to a `featureBranch` and then I open a pull request for it to merge into `VerifyApiTestEnvironment` branch.
I expect to trigger a release and then a deployment every time I do this, but the release is not getting triggered.

Am I missing something related to configuring PR triggers?

Comment: Is the build configured as a validation build on your branch policies? Also, what you're setting up will deploy when a PR is **created**, not when it's **completed**.

Comment: @DanielMann edited my question to include a screenshot related to this. How do I set it up to deploy when PR is *completed*.

Answer (score 4):

The setting of yours has some problem. As Daniel said, it is used to set as deploy with a PR created. In addition, if you want to deploy just after PR is completed, the source of this release should be **Repository** instead of build pipeline.

So, first, you need to change your release source as **Azure Repository**:

[image]

And then, enable **Continuous deployment trigger**. While the PR completed, it means that code change are merged into the target branch of Repository. So, this need to be enabled, or the deploy will not be triggered while the PR is completed.

[image]

In addition, you need to set branch filter, or the deploy will be triggered no matter which branch is changed. Here I set just merge into master branch( PR target branch is master) can trigger this CD.

[image]

For this option, it just be use for the PR created trigger deploy. Since you just want deploy triggered by the PR completed, so you do not need enable it.

Now, if your master has policy that the code change applied successfully only after PR created and verified, the CD will be executed only after PR completed.

For some configuration of policy, **build policy** is used to set build trigger, and **status policy** used to trigger the release.

So, according to your policy setting, it's used to trigger the build first, and then the build will trigger the release. It's not directly trigger the deploy just after the PR completed.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the instructions! Now, the trigger is working as expected. But, facing one issue, my build keeps failing to say merge doesn't have master changes. I have updated the question to include the image of my repo. Do you know why that keeps happening?

Comment: Could you share the error screenshots in your question? Which merge type do you choose while you complete the PR?

Comment: I am using Merge(no fast-forward) type.

Comment: It's so wired. Does the error message displayed on build? after you complete the pr? So, does it can succeed to complete the pr?

Comment: Yup, after I complete the PR, PR is not successful in that case because of the build failure.

Comment: Could you update the screenshots about the error message(source branch missing the changes from master) displayed? If you don't mind, you can change the build status checked in policy as optional. It will still complete the pr successfully even though the build is failed.